# Getting the error code from a command piped to `-replace` in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script, where one of my commands' output is piped to `-replace` to make sure sensitive information isn't logged.

```
$(mycommand do stuff) -replace 'START_SECRET.*?END_SECRET' 'SECRET_ELIDED'
```

However, when `mycommand` fails, the error gets eaten by `-replace` and the script still succeeds where I would like it to fail. How can I get the error code from that command?

I'm open to solutions that don't look quite like this `-replace`, but ideally it would be something where `mycommand` output appears as it is generated, rather than all at once at the end like would happen if I saved the output, checked the error code, and grepped it later.

Comment: What is `mycommand do stuff`? A cmdlet/native app/custom app/other? Read [about_Output_Streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_output_streams) and [about_Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators); then you know that the subexpression operator `$()`  grabs only _success stream_ so your statement "_the error gets eaten by `-replace`_" is at least unclear - if not wrong…

Comment: You're missing a comma between `'START_SECRET.*?END_SECRET'` and `'SECRET_ELIDED'`

Answer (score 0):

Your current example also finishes running before displaying any output. If you want to output as it comes you need to lose the `$(...)`.  Now each line will be  sent down the pipe as they are generated

```
mycommand do stuff | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace 'START_SECRET.*?END_SECRET' 'SECRET_ELIDED' }
```

As for the error "being eaten", I'm not seeing this behavior, even when wrapping in `$(...)`

```
PS C:\temp> $(dir nonexistentpath) -replace '^', '----'
Get-ChildItem: Cannot find path 'C:\temp\nonexistentpath' because it does not exist.
```

even with native applications

```
PS C:\Program Files\GIMP 2\bin> $(.\bzip2.exe sklfjslf)  -replace '^', '----'
bzip2.exe: Can't open input file sklfjslf: No such file or directory.
```

As others have mentioned it's not clear what your command is or even what you are doing with the output.  If you are trying to capture/process the error records as well you will need to redirect them to the success stream using `2>&1`

```
mycommand do stuff 2>&1 | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace 'START_SECRET.*?END_SECRET' 'SECRET_ELIDED' }
```

If the command you are running is a cmdlet you can also instead use `-ErrorVariable` to capture error records instead of redirecting them to the success stream.

```
PS C:\temp> dir nonexistentpath -ErrorVariable errors
Get-ChildItem: Cannot find path 'C:\temp\nonexistentpath' because it does not exist.
PS C:\temp> $errors

Get-ChildItem: Cannot find path 'C:\temp\nonexistentpath' because it does not exist.
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$var = <#your stuff here#>
$var.Replace('START_SECRET.*?END_SECRET','SECRET_ELIDED')
```

Comment: This will wait until `<my stuff here>` finishes running before displaying any output, which I was hoping to avoid.

Comment: Then you have to build the replace into your logic once you get the output that has to changed.

Comment: Either way, if you don't share the code we can't support you.

Comment: please dont post just code as an answer, update you answer with a proper explanation with the code so others can benefit from the answer.